# Add a list of customers to an object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

I have this object that I'm retrieving from antoher microservice.

```
@Service
public class WebClientService {


    public Mono<CuCoPerson> getCuCoPerson(Integer cucoId, String GS_AUTH_TOKEN) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(GET_RELATION_BY_ID + cucoId)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", GS_AUTH_TOKEN)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CuCoPerson.class)
                .map(cuCoPerson -> {
                    List<CustomerRelation> matches = cuCoPerson.getRelatedCustomers()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getSystemId().equals(400) || relation.getSystemId().equals(300) || relation.getSystemId().equals(410))
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getCustomerId().contains("F"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    cuCoPerson.setRelatedCustomers(matches);
                    return cuCoPerson;
                });
    }
```

The controller is as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/getCucoId/{cucoId}")
    public Mono<CuCoPerson> getCucoRelationById(@PathVariable Integer cucoId, @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String GS_AUTH_TOKEN) {

        return webClientService.getCuCoPerson(cucoId, GS_AUTH_TOKEN);
    }
```

It returns a list of related customers like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
        "relatedCustomers": [
            {
                "customerId": "xxx",
                "systemId": 999
            }
        ]
}
```

And now I need to add this list of customers to my PeopleDTO class which is as follows:

```
public class PeopleDTO {

    private String processType;
    private String operation;
    private String entity;
    private String entityType;
    private Long id;
    private Document document;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Customer {
        private String systemId;
        private String customerId;
    }
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

UPDATE:

Here I'm hardcoding my PeopleDTO just as an example:

```
public PeopleDTO createPeople(Long id) {
        PeopleDTO people = new PeopleDTO();
        people.setProcessType("ONLINE");
        people.setOperation("UPDATE");
        people.setEntity("DOCUMENT");
        people.setEntityType("DOCUMENT");
        people.setIdCuco(id);
        people.setDocument(new Document());
        people.setCustomers(......);

    }
```

So the result should be something like this:

```
{
    "type": "ONLINE",
    "operation": "UPDATE",
    "id": 1,
    "entity": "DOCUMENT",
    "entityType": "NIE",
    "documents": {
        "id": 1,
        "additionals": {
            "issuing_authority": "Spain",
            "country_doc": "ES",
            "place_of_birth": "",
            "valid_from": "1995-08-09",
            "valid_to": "0001-01-01"
        },
        "code": "X12345",
        "typeDocument": "NIE"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "relatedCustomers": [
        {
            "customerId": "xxx",
            "systemId": 999
        }
    ]
}
```

The controller that supposed to retrieve this info is:

```
@GetMapping("getId/{cucoId}")
    public PeopleDTO getFullPeople(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return webClientService.createPeople(id);
    }
```

How should I set the customers in here?

Comment: Please add the code that uses `PeopleDTO` and needs the `customer` field set.

Comment: I didn't undestand. What do you mean?

Comment: In your code there are no usages of `PeopleDTO` so it's completely unclear who and where creates (or needs to create) an instance of it which then has to be updated with a list of customers.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I've updated the question so it's more clear now.